# How to preserve the format of command output after it is assigned to a variable in csh?

Tags: shell, logging, freebsd, csh

Now I want to record all user's login messages in freeBSD, so I type `last -f /var/log/utx.log` in freeBSD to see the log.

The output format is:

`brandboat  pts/1    xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx        Sat Nov  1 11:28   still logged in
brandboat  pts/0    xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx        Sat Nov  1 11:21   still logged in
root       ttyv0                           Sat Nov  1 11:16   still logged in
brandboat  pts/1    xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx        Sat Nov  1 11:11 - 11:25  (00:13)`

And I try to copy all of these message in to a variable:

`` set aaa= `last -f /var/log/utx.log`
echo $aaa ``

the output is:

`brandboat pts/1 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx Sat Nov 1 11:28 still logged in brandboat pts/0 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx Sat Nov 1 11:21 still logged in root ttyv0 Sat Nov 1 11:16 still logged in brandboat pts/1 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx Sat Nov 1 11:11 - 11:25 (00:13)`

As you can see, it doesn't keep the original format from the command output. How do I keep it in **csh**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is black magic but it works:

```
$ csh
% set g=`ls | sed -s ':a;N;$\\!ba;s/\n/\\n/g'`
% echo "$g"
% /bin/echo -e "$g"
```

The idea is to change the newlines by `\n` using `sed`. I used this [trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/sed-how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n) to get it. Note that I had to double escape label `!ba` to tell `csh` that it is not an event.

You may replace `ls` by `last -f /var/log/utx.log` to check if it works for you.